# For each case in a dataset, is there a way to sum the total distances between all the labels applied to that case?

Tags: r

For a dataset with several binary variables, I want to create a variable that indicates the total sum of distances between each binary label a case is attached to.

I have a data set with several binary variables that looks like this:

```
  caseid v1 v2 v3 v4
1    one  0  1  0  1
2    two  1  1  0  0
3  three  0  1  1  1
4   four  1  0  1  1
```

Additionally, I have already constructed a distance matrix which shows the distance between any given pairs of variables. It looks like this:

```
   v1    v2   v3   v4
v1  0   0.5  0.3  0.2
v2 0.5   0   0.1  0.8
v3 0.3  0.1   0   0.4
v4 0.2  0.8  0.4   0
```

What I want to do is create a new variable that sums the total distance between all the variables present in each case. For example, for case three I would want a value of (distance between v2 and v3) + (distance between v2 and v4) + (distance between v3 and v4) = 0.1 + 0.8 + 0.4 = 1.3.

The end result would look something like this:

```
  caseid v1 v2 v3 v4 dist
1    one  0  1  0  1  0.8
2    two  1  1  0  0  0.5
3  three  0  1  1  1  1.3
4   four  1  0  1  1  0.9
```

Obviously for this few cases I can do the calculations manually, but my data set has about 800 cases and 16 variables I'm interested. Is there a way to automated this process?

Comment: Do you mean 0.8 as the dist for case one? (the v2/v4 value in your second table)

Comment: Yes. I've my original post to fix the error.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `apply` and `combn` to determine for each row of your dataframe the pairwise combinations you're interested in, retrieve them from your matrix, and sum them:

```
df$dist = apply(df[-1],1,function(x) sum(mat[t(combn(c(1:length(x))[as.logical(x)],2))]))
> df
  caseid v1 v2 v3 v4 dist
1    one  0  1  0  1  0.8
2    two  1  1  0  0  0.5
3  three  0  1  1  1  1.3
4   four  1  0  1  1  0.9
```